# PHP: Getting value of constant of class from string

Tags: php

The example is following：

```php
<?php

class test{
    const A = "1";
    const B = "2";

    public function getStr($a){
        echo self::$a;
    }

}

$c = new test();
$c->getStr("A");


 ?>
```

How can I echo variable "A" in the window, when I use getStr("A")

Comment: You could make a `construct()` function for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [`ReflectionClass::getConstants`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php).

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/870747)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class test{
    const A = "1";
    const B = "2";

    public function getStr($a){

        $class= new ReflectionClass(self::class);//passing class name to ReflectionClass
        echo $class->getConstant($a);//getting required constant.
    }

}

$c = new test();
$c->getStr("A");
```

Comment: Will it support in PHP version 5.4

Comment: @AnkurGarg Yes it do support. You can check the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php

Answer (score 0):

> constant() is useful if you need to retrieve the value of a constant, but do not know its name. I.e. it is stored in a variable or returned by a function.

**[Constant Doc](https://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)**

```
echo constant("self::".$a);
```